# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, multer

I am new to multer npm package. I have built a form with few text input fields and file upload fields. When I entered all fields and submit, data gets saved and file uploaded, all working fine. But clicked submit directly without uploading files then it gives this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename')

Note: I am using React.js and Node.js mongoDB

Form

```
<div className={`container ${addEventModule.addEventContainer}`}>
    <form onSubmit={this.addEventHandler} encType="multipart/form-data">
        <div className={addEventModule.addEventForm}>
            <div className={`text-center ${addEventModule.title}`}>
                <h3 style={{ color: '#2557A7'}}>Add Event</h3>
            </div>

            <hr />

            <div className="text-center text-danger" style={this.state.others.errormessage ? {visibility: 'visible'} : {visibility: 'hidden'} }>
                <span>{this.state.others.errormessage}</span>
            </div>

            <div className={addEventModule.addEventBody}>
                <div className={`row ${addEventModule.marginBottom}`}>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <Input type="text" label="Event Name" name="event_name" onchange={ (e) => this.inputChangeHandler(e) } value={this.state.inputs.event_name.value} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <span className="text-danger">{this.state.inputs.event_name.error === 1 ? this.state.inputs.event_name.errormessage : ''}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className={`row ${addEventModule.marginBottom}`}>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <Textarea type="text" label="Event Description" name="event_description" onchange={ (e) => this.inputChangeHandler(e) } value={this.state.inputs.event_description.value} rows="5" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <span className="text-danger">{this.state.inputs.event_description.error === 1 ? this.state.inputs.event_description.errormessage : ''}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className={`row ${addEventModule.marginBottom}`}>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <Input type="date" label="Event Date" name="event_date" onchange={ (e) => this.inputChangeHandler(e) } value={this.state.inputs.event_date.value} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <span className="text-danger">{this.state.inputs.event_date.error === 1 ? this.state.inputs.event_date.errormessage : ''}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className={`row ${addEventModule.marginBottom}`}>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <Input type="file" label="Event Image" name="event_image" onchange={ (e) => this.inputChangeHandler(e) } />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <span className="text-danger">{this.state.inputs.event_image.error === 1 ? this.state.inputs.event_image.errormessage : ''}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className={`row ${addEventModule.marginBottom}`}>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <Select label="Event Category" name="event_category" onchange={ (e) => this.inputChangeHandler(e) } value={this.state.inputs.event_category.value} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <span className="text-danger">{this.state.inputs.event_category.error === 1 ? this.state.inputs.event_category.errormessage : ''}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div className={`row ${addEventModule.marginBottom}`}>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label className="form-label">Event Enabled</label>
                            <Radio type="radio" name="event_enabled" onchange={ (e) => this.inputChangeHandler(e) } value="Yes" labelValue="Yes" />
                            <Radio type="radio" name="event_enabled" onchange={ (e) => this.inputChangeHandler(e) } value="No" labelValue="No" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <span className="text-danger">{this.state.inputs.event_enabled.error === 1 ? this.state.inputs.event_enabled.errormessage : ''}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div className={addEventModule.addEventFooter}>
                <div className={`row ${addEventModule.marginBottom}`}>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <Button type="submit">Add Event</Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

onsubmit function

```
addEventHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const event_name = this.state.inputs.event_name.value;
    const event_description = this.state.inputs.event_description.value;
    const event_date = this.state.inputs.event_date.value;
    const event_image = this.state.inputs.event_image.value;
    const event_category = this.state.inputs.event_category.value;
    const event_enabled = this.state.inputs.event_enabled.value;
    const event_featured = 'No';
    
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('event_name',event_name);
    formData.append('event_description',event_description);
    formData.append('event_date',event_date);
    formData.append('event_image',event_image);
    formData.append('event_category',event_category);
    formData.append('event_enabled',event_enabled);
    formData.append('event_featured',event_featured);

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost:4000/sports-event/add-event',
        data: formData
    }).then( response => {
        if(response.data.code === 0){
            alert(response.data.message);
            const initialStateOthers = {
                ...initialEventState.others
            }
            initialStateOthers['submitRedirect'] = 1;
            this.setState({ ...this.state, others: initialStateOthers });
        }else if(response.data.code === 2){
            let duplicateStateInputs = {
                ...this.state.inputs
            }
            const fieldValue = [this.state.inputs.event_name.value, this.state.inputs.event_description.value,this.state.inputs.event_date.value,this.state.inputs.event_image.value,this.state.inputs.event_category.value,this.state.inputs.event_enabled.value];
            const fieldArray = [this.state.inputs.event_name.type, this.state.inputs.event_description.type,this.state.inputs.event_date.type,this.state.inputs.event_image.type,this.state.inputs.event_category.type,this.state.inputs.event_enabled.type];
            for(let i = 0; i < fieldArray.length; i++){
                if(response.data.field === fieldArray[i]){
                    duplicateStateInputs = empty_field_validation(duplicateStateInputs, fieldArray[i], fieldValue[i], response.data.message);
                }else{
                    duplicateStateInputs = empty_field_validation(duplicateStateInputs, fieldArray[i], fieldValue[i], '');
                }
            }
            this.setState({ ...this.state, inputs: duplicateStateInputs});
        }else{
            const initialStateInputs = {
                ...initialEventState.inputs
            }
            const initialStateOthers = {
                ...initialEventState.others
            }
            initialStateInputs['event_name'].value = this.state.inputs.event_name.value;
            initialStateOthers['errormessage'] = response.data.message;
            this.setState({ ...this.state, inputs: initialStateInputs, others: initialStateOthers });
        }
    }).catch( err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Node.js

```
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, path.join(__dirname,'../public/Images'));
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
    }
});

const fileFilter = function(req, file, cb){
    if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png'){
        cb(null, true);
    }else{
        cb(null, false);
    }
}

const fileUpload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: fileFilter
}).single('event_image');

router.post('/sports-event/add-event', fileUpload, eventController.addEvent);
```

addEvent Controller

```
exports.addEvent = (req, res, next) => {
const event_name =req.body.event_name;
const event_description=req.body.event_description;
const event_date=req.body.event_date;
const event_image=req.file;
const imagePath = 'Images/' + req.file.filename;
const event_category=req.body.event_category;
const event_enabled=req.body.event_enabled;
const event_featured= req.body.event_featured;

// ------------------- Validations -----------------------------
if(Event.check_field_if_empty(event_name) == 1){
    return res.json({
        code: 2,
        message: `Event Name is mandatory`,
        field: 'event_name'
    });
}else if(!Event.event_name_regex(event_name)){
    return res.json({
        code: 2,
        message: `Event name must contain only capitals letters`,
        field: `event_name`
    })
}else if(Event.check_field_if_empty(event_description) === 1){
    return res.json({
        code: 2,
        message: `Event Description is mandatory`,
        field: 'event_description'
    });
}else if(!Event.only_letters_numbers(event_description)){
    return res.json({
        code: 2,
        message: `Event Description must contain only letters and numbers, no special characters`,
        field: 'event_description'
    });
}else if(Event.check_field_if_empty(event_date) === 1){
    return res.json({
        code: 2,
        message: `Event Date is mandatory`,
        field: 'event_date'
    });
}else if(Event.check_field_if_empty(event_image) === 1){
    return res.json({
        code: 2,
        message: `Event Image is mandatory`,
        field: 'event_image'
    });
}else if(Event.check_field_if_empty(event_category) === 1){
    return res.json({
        code: 2,
        message: `Event Category is mandatory`,
        field: 'event_category'
    });
}else if(Event.check_field_if_empty(event_enabled) === 1){
    return res.json({
        code: 2,
        message: `Event Enabled is mandatory`,
        field: 'event_enabled'
    });
}    

Event.check_if_events_exists(event_name, event_category).then( response => {
    if(response.length > 0){
        res.json({
            code: 1,
            message: "This Events already exists"
        });
    }else{
        Event.add_event(event_name, event_description, event_date, imagePath, event_category, event_enabled, event_featured).then( response => {
            res.json({
                code: 0,
                message: "Event Added Successfully"
            });
        }).catch( err => {
            return res.json({
                code: 1,
                message: `Error : ${err}`
            });
        });
    }
}).catch( err => {
    return res.json({
        code: 1,
        message: `Error : ${err}`
    });
});
 }
```

The above validations are not working.

Comment: First, please understand _exactly_ what your code is doing, and what line and file the error originated. Please provide the *minimal reproducible code*.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this error but mine was fixed by changing path.dirname(process.main.filename) to path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename), in my model. although I was using express.